# How can I print contents of JTone and C# object in log

Tags: c#

I am trying to write the contents of two simple objects a JTOKEN and a c# OBJECT to a log as follows

```
log.LogInformation($"Jongel: {onlineVariant} \n\n\n Fibbel: {storeVariantModel}");
```

But when I do this it does not print the contents it only prints the type of object

I tried adding .ToString() but that also dont help

WHat can I do to print the contents?

Comment: How about `onlineVariant.ToObject<string>()`?

Comment: Can you add more code where `onlineVariant` and `storeVariantModel`  are declared. What is expected output and what currently printing

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by two approach, lets assume you have a model like this:

```
public class OnlineVariant
{
    public string Online { get; set; }

    public string Variant { get; set; }

}
```

1- Override ToString method for your class

```
 public class OnlineVariant
  {
    public string Online { get; set; }

    public string Variant { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(Online)}: {Online} -- {nameof(Variant)}: {Variant}";
    }
  }
```

And in your log try this:

```
log.LogInformation($"Jongel: {onlineVariant.ToString()} \n\n\n Fibbel: {storeVariantModel.ToString()}");
```

2- Convert model to json string using newtonsoft.json

```
log.LogInformation($"Jongel: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(onlineVariant)} \n\n\n Fibbel: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storeVariantModel)}");
```